# MVC Model not posting

Tags: post, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, model, null

When I click the login button I never get my model posted to the server. However if I accept a FormCollection I will see the values. How can I make this automatically bind to my model instead of searching the Form Collection?

From what I have read there are a few common problems for this:

1 - your view does not specify what model you are using (@model myApp.Models.name)

2 - Your model does not use properties

3 - Any of the required fields are missing

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Password()
{
    return View(new AuthViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Password(AuthViewModel password)
{
    if (password == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Password))
    {
        ViewBag.Error = Constants.ErrorMessages.UserPassword_PassBlank;
        return View(new AuthViewModel());
    }

    //success
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

**Model**

```
public class AuthViewModel
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.AuthViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Password";
}

<h2>Password</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password,new{placeholder="Password",type="password",autofocus=""})</div>
    <div><button id="btnLogin" type="submit">Login</button></div>
    <div class="error">@ViewBag.Error</div>
}
```

Comment: i am not sure if this is how mvc is supposed to be implemented, my views return data to the controller which passes the data onto my model (the logic)

Comment: I use any 'ViewModel' to handle passing data but they have no logic in them. Do you then always use the FormCollection to get data from a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why Dan's answer isn't working without trying it, looks like it should.
I took a look at some of my code for a login form, similar to yours.
Here's mine :

```
public class SignInModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Enter your email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Enter your password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

The main difference I see is that mine has the [DataType(DataType.Password)] attribute on the password. Not sure if this makes that much difference though.

The other thing I noticed is different is that in my form I specify that the form method is POST. Also I've used the `EditorFor()` helper instead of textbox or password:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", "POST"))
{
    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="form-remember">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.RememberMe)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">
        Sign In</button>
}
```

Comment: I managed to get it to submit the password by changing the parameter name on the controller... Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue: http://codeblog.shawson.co.uk/mvc-strongly-typed-view-returns-a-null-model-on-post-back/

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)</div>
    <div><input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Login"/></div>
    <div class="error">@ViewBag.Error</div>
}
```

Comment: Do I have to make any changes to my model to store the password? If I just make that change it still does not work.

Comment: No need to change anything else. Just the view. I have updated it. Copy and paste what I wrote and it should work.

Comment: I copied your code and I still receive null instead of a model as a parameter for controller.